# Use global or constant variable in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say we have a connection to memcache or redis... which style is preferred and why?

```
MEMCACHE = Memcache.new(...)
REDIS = Redis.new(...)
```

OR

```
$memcache = Memcache.new(...)
$redis = Redis.new(...)
```

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 45):

You might want to use `Redis.current` More info [here](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L23)

For example, in an initializer:

```
Redis.current = Redis.new(host: 'localhost', port: 6379)
```

And then in your other classes:

```
def stars
  redis.smembers("stars")
end

private

def redis
  Redis.current
end
```

Comment: Nice solution to 'Do not introduce global variables.' errors by rubocop gem.

Answer (score 9):

They are not equivalent constructs. Depending on your application, they may or may not be interchangeable, but they are semantically different.

```
# MEMCACHE is a constant, subject to scoping constraints.
MEMCACHE = Memcache.new(...)

# $memcache is a global variable: declare it anywhere; use it anywhere.
$memcache = Memcache.new(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO a "constant", because it communicates that it's supposed to be... constant.

Globals don't imply they shouldn't be mutated.

Comment: Yes. Another solution to consider might be to extend the classes to include something like `Memcache.connection` and `Redis.connection`, (a bit like `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`) although it might get a bit verbose to code with those if they are used a lot, but this way the "constants" are attached to their origins.

Comment: @Casper Probably even better idea, yep.