# $redis global variable with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am using redis as a read cache.  I have created an initializer

config/initializer/redis.rb

```
$redis = Redis.new(:host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"], :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
```

I am using this global in my unicorn.rb to create a new connection whenever a new worker is created.

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # clear redis connection
  $redis.quit unless $redis.blank?
end

# Give each child process its own Redis connection
after_fork do |server, worker|
  $redis = Redis.new(:host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"], :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
end
```

I am also using this global variable whenever I need to access my redis servers.  But I am not comfortable using this global variable.  Are there any better options than using global variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16474679/19079 answers this better than any of the answers below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

expanding further on mestachs suggestion, namespacing a module in your initializer as below

config/initializers/redis.rb

```
module ReadCache
  class << self
    def redis
      @redis ||= Redis.new(:url => (ENV["REDIS_URL"] || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'))
    end
  end
end
```

then in unicorn.rb

```
 before_fork do |server, worker|
    ...
   if defined?(ReadCache.redis)
    ReadCache.redis.quit
   end
    ...
 end

 after_fork do |server, worker|
    ...
   if defined?(ReadCache.redis)
    ReadCache.redis.client.reconnect
   end
    ...
 end
```

Comment: So, if I have thousand unique requests simultaneously, I would also need thousand connexions to the redis server, right?

Comment: @Kira Can you explain a bit more.  I dont think it will need thousand connections.  If I understand correctly, This module will be common to the whole app.

Comment: this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections helps alot with understanding connection pooling weather or not your using Heroku. with a bit of understanding from that you can them tune your sidekiq concurrency see: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#wiki-concurrency.

Comment: @blotto that was a nice reading, thank you. Although, your sample code it's not using ActiveRecord (correct me if I'm wrong), so the pooling technique it's not being used and still we have a redis connection per client/worker.

Comment: @Kira, it really depends on your setup. my example presumes ActiveRecord (Rails), and a forking server such as Unicorn. there would actually be more than one connection per dyno/worker. Calculating concurrency, and ultimately defining such settings, is a balance between your allowed db connections, and how much you want to scale.

Comment: Use `Redis.current` as detailed by @NobodysNightmare below.

Comment: since it is still the accepted answer, cannot delete this post in order to promote the more accurate answer below.

Answer (score 100):

There is `Redis.current`, which you can use to store your one-and-only `Redis` instance.

So instead of using `$redis`, you can assign your instance as follows:

```
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"], :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
```

`Redis.current` was [introduced to redis-rb in 2010](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/commit/23ed5974e96e89f4ef691139a9380a9d08e9cec6) as a standard way to grab a redis connection, so I was surprised that no other answer mentioned it.

**Update:** Starting with version 4.6.0 `Redis.current` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/commit/9745e22db65ac294be51ed393b584c0f8b72ae98). The author notes that typical multi-threaded applications will find a lot of locking around a shared redis client. They recommend to define an own place to get a redis client, but also suggest to use a connection pool.

The accepted answer is therefore the simplest solution to achieve something comparable to `Redis.current`, but may not perform optimal in multi-threaded environments.

Comment: Annoyingly this was the answer I was looking for, but because it was below the accepted answer, I wasted time not doing this.

Comment: IMHO this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: It's now deprecated. Surprise. How fun.

Comment: I filed an issue asking for "official" recommendations: https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/issues/1064

Comment: @courtsimas Thanks for noticing this. I've asked in the corresponding commit and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @NobodysNightmare I'm impressed and thanks. That's a quick and thorough update.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't  already use another Rails.cache I advise you to just use that mechanism with redis.

The gem redis-store makes this realy easy (https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store)

This way you can just do `Rails.cache.reconnect` and all is dandy

https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store/issues/21#issuecomment-948569

It also allows you to use the awesome Rails.cache API, which has some neat features: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html

Answer (score 0):

A more **namespaced** option to replace your global variable, you can create a method in a module

```
module Caching
  def self.redis
    ... initialize/memoize/reconnect here...
  end
end
```

You than then call it with:

`Caching.redis`

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

you can use `constant` instead of `global variable`.like in
    config/initializer/redis.rb

```
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"], :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
```

and in unicorn.rb

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  # clear redis connection
  REDIS.quit if defined?(REDIS)
end
```

# Give each child process its own Redis connection

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  REDIS ||= Redis.new(:host => ENV["REDIS_HOST"], :port => ENV["REDIS_PORT"])
end
```

Comment: sounds interesting, what is the role of this constant? I mean, it's not a global variable but it behaves similar as if it were a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#using-redis-on-unicorn) Heroku, you don't need to add `$redis` to your Unicorn:

> No special setup is required when using Redis Cloud with a Unicorn server. Users running Rails apps on Unicorn should follow the instructions in the [Configuring Redis from Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#configuring-redis-on-rails) section and users...

Here's all the "[Configuring Redis from Rails](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rediscloud#configuring-redis-on-rails) section" has for before Rails 4 (besides the Gemfile and some other pre-Rails 3 stuff):

```
# config/initalizers/redis.rb

if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
  $redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
end
```

It doesn't really give an explanation as to why "no special setup is required".

Comment: I know that you do need to do something special. I have maxed out 512 connection redis cloud instances on production heroku servers using unicorn.