# Setting up Redis To Go with Heroku and Rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redistogo

I am attempting to setup Redis To Go on my Rails 4 app. I want to be able to deploy it to Heroku as well.

So far, this is what I've done:

Through the `dashboard.heroku` site, I used the one click install for the Nano version of Redis To Go to install the addon to my app.

I added `gem 'redis'` to my gemfile.

In `config/environments/development.rb` I added this line:

```
ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] = 'redis://redistogo:b9fc604b1c86a1f6c232ce1dd16cd989@albacore.redistogo.com:10280/'
```

Then, I created a `config/initializers/redis.rb` file which looks like this:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["redis://redistogo:b9fc604b1c86a1f6d872ce1dd16cd989@albacore.redistogo.com:10280/"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

When running a `Redis` command in my console now, I get this error:

`Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)`

What am I doing wrong here, and what do I need to do to ensure that I can test in development and deploy to Heroku without any issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] should be in the environment on Heroku. I'd remove it from config/environments/development.rb altogether and change the redis.rb initializer to:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV.fetch("REDISTOGO_URL", "redis://localhost:6379/"))
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

As long as that ENV var isn't set in development, it'll fall back to the local redis installation.

Answer (score 2):

To update [brandonhilkert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22457954/1789900) for Rails 4:

```
uri = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/"
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```

Also, you might want to use `Redis.current` instead of setting a `REDIS` variable ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16474679/1789900)).

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 4 I did the following

In the console:

```
heroku addons:create redistogo
heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISTOGO_URL
```

In my `Procfile` I added:

```
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

In my 'gemfile.rb' I added:

```
gem 'redis'
```

I added the following file, `config/initializers/redis.rb`:

```
uri = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/"
REDIS = Redis.new(:url => uri)
```